# Validate 2 dropdown list (country and state)

Tags: php

I have 2 dropdown list, 1 country and 1 state, the value of country is already autocoded or shown but can't get the state to show properly.

Comment: Can you create snippet to reproduce the problem?

Comment: So you're trying to get the value of the selected option from the dropdown menu?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to show the list for states based on the autocoded value from country

Comment: can you show HTML code as well?

Comment: Thanks @david, i'm new in javascript and I already above issue :)